# The Frattini subuniverse is the intersections of all proper maximal subuniverses

Tags: universal-algebra

From "Universal Algebra: Fundamentals and Selected Topics" of Clifford Bergman.

> An element $a$ of an algebra $A$ is called a non-generator of $A$ if
>   for every $X \subseteq  A$,  $A  =  Sg(X  \cup  \{a\})$ implies $A  = Sg(X)$.
>
> (a) Prove that the set of nongenerators of $A$ forms a  subuniverse,
>   $Frat(A)$  (called the Frattini subuniverse of $A$).
>
> (b) Prove that $Frat(A)$ is the intersection of all maximal proper
>   subuniverses  of  $A$. (If you wish,  you can assume that $A$ is
>   finite. To do the infinite  case, you will need Zorn’s lemma.)

**My solution for (a)**

Suppose $a_1, ..., a_n$ to be non-gerators of $A$ and $f$ a fundamental operation of **A** then:

$X \cup \{f(a_1,..., a_n)\} \subseteq X \cup \{a_1, ..., a_n \} \cup \{f(a_1,..., a_n)\}$

It's easy to see that:

$Sg(X \cup \{a_1, ..., a_n \} \cup \{f(a_1,..., a_n)\})=Sg(X \cup \{a_1, ..., a_n \})=Sg(X)$

Hence $Sg(X \cup \{f(a_1,..., a_n)\}) \subseteq Sg(X)$ and the other verse of inclusion is trivial.

**My question**

I'm looking for a proof of (b).

Comment: Disclaimer: I've never heard about universal algebras before. This looks like a general case of the equivalent definition of Frattini's subgroup, whose proof can be found [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_definitions_of_Frattini_subgroup). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  = {Mᵢ : i ∈ I} be the collection of all maximal proper subuniverses of A.

Let Frat(A) be the collection of non-generators of A.

To show: ⋂  = Frat(A)

1. Frat(A) ⊆ ⋂ .  Let u be a non-generator of A and show that ∀i ∈ I, u ∈ Mᵢ as follows: Fix i. If u does not belong to Mᵢ, then Sg(Mᵢ,u) = A. But then Mᵢ = Sg(Mᵢ) = A, since u is a non-generator. On the other hand, Mᵢ is proper. This contradiction proves that u belongs to Mᵢ, and i was arbitrary.
2. ⋂  ⊆ Frat(A).  Let u ∈ ⋂ . We prove u is a non-generator. Suppose A = Sg (X ∪ {u}) for some X ⊆ A.  To see that Sg(X) = A, suppose the contrary; i.e., Sg(X) ≠ A. Then (by Zorn's Lemma) there exists a maximal proper subuniverse M ≤ A containing Sg(X).  But then u ∈ ⋂  ⊆ M implies that M contains both X and u and thus M contains A = Sg (X ∪ {u}), contradicting the fact that M is proper. ∎